# Tensorflow set_seed error when running autoencoder

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to run the code from here,
https://medium.com/@abien.agarap/implementing-an-autoencoder-in-tensorflow-2-0-5e86126e9f7

but am getting this error,

> File
>   "C:/Users/rupert/Versioning/PCTSoftware/Libraries/python/tensorflow/autoencoders/autoencoder-full.py",
>   line 12, in 
>       tf.random.set_seed(1)
>
> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v1.random' has no attribute
>   'set_seed'

Any ideas on how to resolve?

Tensorflow 1.13
Windows 7

Comment: hi, i can't access the code in the mentioned link, could you share it with me please ? ali.1986.kasim@gmail.com. thanks

Answer (score 29):

Try this:

```
tf.random.set_random_seed(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

As you can see, the post is focusing on the version 2.0.0 of `tensorflow`. You should run their code with their version.